# Grails 2.4.4 Map of Objects example not being persisted to Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, grails-2.4

I was following [Grails 2.4.4 documentation to make a Map of Objects](http://docs.grails.org/2.4.4/guide/GORM.html#sets,ListsAndMaps), but my objects were not being persisted to Mongo DB. So, I decided to make a sanity check using the exactly same example provided by the documentation and it also did not work.

Steps:

> grails create-app test

Next, I included the mongo plugin to my BuilConfig.groovy :

```
compile ":mongodb:3.0.3"
//runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1"
```

Then, I configured my DataSource.groovy:

```
environments {
    production {
        grails {
            mongo {
                replicaSet = [ "xxxxxxxx"]
                username = "xxxx"
                password= "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                databaseName = "xxxxxx"
            }
        }
    }
    development {
        grails {
            mongo {
                replicaSet = [ "xxxxxxxx"]
                username = "xxxx"
                password= "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                databaseName = "xxxxxx"
            }
        }
    }
    test {
        grails {
            mongo {
                replicaSet = [ "xxxxxxxx"]
                username = "xxxx"
                password= "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                databaseName = "xxxxxx"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Book domain class:

```
package test

class Book {

    String name
    Map authors
    static hasMany = [authors:Author]

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

And here is my Author domain class:

```
package test

class Author {

    String name
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

using the grails console, I ran the following script :

```
import test.*

def a = new Author(name:"Stephen King")

def book = new Book(name:"test")
book.authors = ["stephen":a]
book.save(failOnError:true)
```

And then, I took a look at my Mongo DB and I could  not find the map that was supposed to be persisted.

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "test",
    "version": 0
}
```

I really appreciate if you have any clues of what is going on or if you know any workaround to persist a `Map`in Grails.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. Add the following to your `Book` domain class:

```
static embedded = ["authors"]
```

On the second thought, why are you using a `Map` instead of `List` for `authors`?

Since this is a MongoDB database, it will save all the fields of `Author`.

Comment: Thanks @Shashank. This is just the example provided by the documentation which I will be using in a similar way. The embedded component saves the whole object, but what I need is just the "reference" to an existing object. It would be something like the following: 
`book: {
 "authors":
     {
  "awarded":2131,
  "acknowledged":324324,
  "mentioned": 6575234,
     }
}`